# How to update PhpStorm to comment <?= ?> tag to <?php //= ?> instead of <? //= ?> which is creating error

Tags: phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm 2017.1.4.

I am unable to find option for how to update PhpStorm PHP single line comment  `<?= ?>` tag to `<?php //= ?>` instead of `<? //= ?>` which generates PHP error.

Comment: What PHP error it generates? I commented `<?= 4+5; ?>` and got `<?//= 4+5; ?>` - that produces no errors and file can be launched as PHP script without any issues.

Comment: Vlad, it is a difference in the server config. See my answer

Comment: @cornel.raiu Thanks! Forgot about this one!

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that error because your PHP setup does not have "short_open_tag" on.

Turn it on in your php.ini and your comment will be valid.

I am almost 100% sure there is no setting for that in PHPStorm.

Edit: This is to confirm what I said about the setting: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2059

It is a planned feature but not sure when it will be done.

Comment: @AnilSinghBafila if it helped, please select the answer as correct :)